# Text from String resourse not display in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView


        android:text="@string/zagalni"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C9CC85"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#455B2A"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my code, text is large, but in TextView is nothing. I tried to type text from keyboard, tried to copy/paste - nothing. Please help to solve it.

Comment: Probably need to wrap_content the height of both LinearLayout, and TextView

Comment: tried that too.

Comment: could you share the whole XML file? Markup above works fine as is, tested on android 11 in a constraintlayout.

Comment: Press "R" on XML file and try once

Comment: In case you are just not seeing the text in the designer: Go to `res/values/styles.xml` and change `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`